# IIS URL appending website name

Tags: asp.net, .net, url, iis

I have configured a website and its running fine in IIS.

Suppose i type "localhost" in the URL, i can see the website loaded without any issues.But, i am facing issues, whenever i type "localhost" in the URL box, URL is getting appended with the website name as `"localhost\websitename"`

But i want the site to be loaded just by typing "localhost" not by changing to `"localhost\websitename"`.

i have tried checking the IIS setting but no joy. Could you please help?

Comment: Create a dummy html file, e.g. `c:\temp\test.html` with just `<a href="http://localhost/">Test</a>`. Load the file in browser, click the link, does the URL then get replaced? If so then there is a Redirect going on and then you need to find what causes this. Could be you installed website in a virtual dir without realizing it.

Comment: yes its redirecting to localhost\websitename

Comment: Check your IIS settings and web.config first. You have to find the cause of that redirect. Check for any URL Rewrite module related configuration exist by looking into your web.config and IIS. Also look for <httpRedirect> related configuration..

Comment: And post your IIS site schema, bindings configuration etc. pls

Comment: binding is just port 80